# How to remove the line between the content and the arrow in combobox control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox with below design.

[image]

But now I want to make it look like this, no seperate line with the arrow.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I have customized a style for ComboBox, here is my code for style:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ComboBoxButton" Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="SelectedContentBorder" Margin="2,2,1,2">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownButton" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ComboBoxButton" Width="Auto"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="13">
                                                            <Path x:Name="ArrowDownPath" Data="M 0 0 L 5 5 L 10 0" Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Chrome" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <MultiTrigger>
                                                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                                                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Chrome" Value="#FFC2E0FF"/>
                                                        </MultiTrigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Chrome" Value="#FF3399FF"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Chrome" Value="#FF99CCFF"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowDownPath" Value="#FFB5B2B5"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1,1,0,1" MinHeight="18" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBox.Style>
                            </TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Background" Value="#FFF7F7F7"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" TargetName="Background" Value="2"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FFB5B2B5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" TargetName="Background" Value="2"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="LightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="SelectedContentBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="DropDownButton" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ContentSite" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="DropDownButton" Value="#FF3399FF"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="DropDownButton" Value="#FFC2E0FF"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FF3399FF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="DropDownButton" Value="#FF3399FF"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="DropDownButton" Value="#FFC2E0FF"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FF3399FF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" TargetName="Shdw" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Sorry for lack of information.

Comment: MSDN: "[Create or modify a template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908(v=expression.40).aspx)"

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @HariPrasad Updated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownButton" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1"
```

This is probably the issue causing line of code. 
Change it to below code or whatever you need. It should work.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownButton" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
```